# OnClickListener in a while loop

Tags: java, while-loop, onclicklistener

(Updated Text per request)I am a new Android programmer and I am working on a simple stop watch program. I have some experience with c++ but little with java or xml of which android uses both, hence my being here. My question relates to the java aspect.

I have two issues. My program works to update the time elapsed when I click on the stop button, but what I would like to add is a dynamically updating textbox with the time elapsed. I tried to create a while loop that would just run the time until I clicked stop but it ignores the stop button and is trapped in the while loop because I don't know how to tell it to stop. Perhaps a better way to go about this would be a runnable.

My second problem is that it does not display the time at all in that while loop even though I know what I have is correct as far as formatting goes. So my question is will this go away if the computer isn't trapped in that while loop?

I realize nothing I have said is super clear, maybe somebody can just point me to a good simple explanation of this kind of thing somewhere? I did not include my code because it isn't an error in my code as much as it is, I just don't know how to do it.

Comment: What language? maybe post your code?

Comment: @TomerArazy the tag says JAVA.

Comment: I added that tag because the OP mentioned Runnable. @logixologist

Comment: @logixologist - As 11684 said - there was no tag when I posted my comment

Comment: For the first couple comments, sorry that I don't know the system yet since this was my first question...I will try and do better. But thanks to ddriver for the answer, looks good, I will try it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No loops are necessary - the usual practice for this task is to use timers and have everything event driven. You would typically have an "elapsed timer" which measures elapsed time, as well as a timer that tracks an interval and triggers a callback every time that interval of time has passed. Since you haven't specified a programming language and a framework, I am going for some pseudo code:

```
void updateUI() {
   textbox.setText(et.elapsedTime());
}

void stop() {
   t.stop();
   textbox.setText("Total time was " + et.elapsedTime());
   et.stop;
}

void start() {
   et.start();
   t.start();
}

ElapsedTimer et;
Timer t(200, updateUI); // timer with interval 200 msec updateUI()
```

So you basically bind the start button to the start function, the stop button to the stop function, and while the timers are running you will periodically update the elapsed time in your UI. When stop is clicked you will get the final time.

Note that you could also do it asynchronously, but inter-thread communication is usually queued and slow enough to affect more precise measurements.

EDIT: Just noticed Java was added to the tags, will leave this answer for reference anyway.

EDIT 2: I am not aware of how Java implements a Runnable, but the Runnable I've used in Qt is not particularly great when transferring data frequently to the main thread where the GUI resides. Basically, the idea of a Runnable is to start an asynchronous task and only be informed when it is completed, the bare minimal amount of "signaling" between threads. Especially in this particular scenario, where the transferred value is an indication of time, that may very well be inaccurate until it is reached in the queue to be displayed. That is why I don't recommend a Runnable interface for that particular task.

Answer (score 0):

I assumed you are using Java (because you mentioned `Runnable`). If that's the case, you could do something like this:

```
public class MyClockRunnable implements Runnable {
    public bool running = true;

    public void run() {
        while(running) {
            // Update the time and other things you need done here
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        }
    }
}
```

And then, from the calling class:

```
public class AppController {
    public AppController() {
        //on start call 
        // MyClockRunnable clock = new MyClockRunnable();
        // new Thread(clock).start();
        stopButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) { clock.running = false; }
        }
    }
}
```